# expo entity not found

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I made a build for Android last week and everything works well. I have made some changes and now I want to make another build with `expo build: android` and I get this error.

Checking if this build already exists…

```
Entity Not Found.
```

It works well in iOS but I couldn’t make the build for Android. any thoughts?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this error by changing the "slug" value to something else in the app.json file

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this issue, tried a bunch of things. not sure which resolved it but here is a list.

#### How it started - a guess of how the issue originated

In `app.json` file I changed the value of `android.package` from "io.expo.client" to "com.mydomain.myapp"

```
"android": {
 "package": "com.expo.client", // ---> "com.mydomain.myapp"
 "adaptiveIcon": {
  "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
  "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
 }
},
```

Then after that and a few other changes `expo build:android` resulted in an error `Entity Not Found.`

#### The fix - try the following to hopefully resolve your issue

- delete all builds of the app from the project in expo
- delete the project
- create a new project
- make sure the slug names match with that in your `app.json` file
- run `expo build:android -c` on your app terminal to build with new credentials
- accept to delete the old credentials
- accept to have Keystore generated for you by expo

Answer (score 0):

Deleting all builds of the app from the project in Expo alone helped me.
Don't forget to refresh the page between builds removal as changes do not immediatlety reflected

Answer (score 0):

try to build with `--clear-credentials` flag...

or try in another expo account.